# Laravel artisan serve very slow serving pages

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have an installation of laravel 5.1.
From a certain point on the artisan server has became very slow.
Anyone have some idea or some direction to point to solve this situation? I's very frustrating to develop in this conditions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use virtual host instead of artisan server.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to configure a virtual host for a Laravel Project.

its easy to run project.not every time to write php artisan serve command for run the project